# How can I Access to template controls in datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate

I'm trying to access a control which is inside the control template of a datagrid control in code behind.

myxaml.xaml :

```
<DataGrid >
.
.
.
<DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="discountGridTextcolumn" >
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBox Name="discountText"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="discountType"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
.
.
.
```

mybehind.cs :

```
var comboBox = GetTemplateChild("discountType");
```

I get null reference.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If It return null,you must place them in the `OnApplyTemplate()` method:
for example

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    base.OnApplyTemplate();

   var comboBox = GetTemplateChild("discountType") as ComboBox;
}
```

Also try this [How to access Control Template parts from Code Behind](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/179105/How-to-access-Control-Template-parts-from-Code-Beh)

**Updated**

From [How to: Find DataTemplate-Generated Elements:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613579.aspx)

```
DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)(yourgrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(yourgrid.SelectedItem));
DataGridDetailsPresenter presenter = FindVisualChild<DataGridDetailsPresenter>(row);
DataTemplate template = presenter.ContentTemplate;
ComboBox Com= (ComboBox)template.FindName("discountType", presenter);
```

FindVisualChild Function:

```
private childItem FindVisualChild<childItem>(DependencyObject obj)
    where childItem : DependencyObject
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
        if (child != null && child is childItem)
            return (childItem)child;
        else
        {
            childItem childOfChild = FindVisualChild<childItem>(child);
            if (childOfChild != null)
                return childOfChild;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Another solution [How to access objects (comboBox, TextBox...) in DataTemplate](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/31c4f3fb-e6c9-446d-9b37-6c9d6723e79a)

Comment: @irsog thanks for your attention but in mycode, presenter.ContentTemplate return null value.

Answer (score 3):

Went through many places and finally made my own solution, it is quite easy:

Let's say we want to get access to a CheckBox named "mycb" in row 0 column 2 of your dataGrid:

```
ContentPresenter cell = dataGrid.Columns[2].GetCellContent(dataGrid.Items[0]) as ContentPresenter;
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)cell.ContentTemplate.FindName("mycb", cell);
```